# WindowsError: [Error 123] while using Get Directory of SSHLibrary

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I'm trying to download a specific directory from Windows XP and Windows Server 2012 using a Get Directory method of SSHLibrary. This directory is on a different volume that the one in which the ssh connection it's established. For clarity when I open the connection this points to volume C:, the source directory is in volume D:. The issue that I'm seeing is that on my local machine the path to directory tries to include the volume letter resulting in something like: `C:\path\to\robot\executable\D:\source\directory` thus resulting in `WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:`

Is there a way to not have this issue but result in a path like `C:\path\to\robot\executable\source\directory` and successfully download the directory? I've tried doing `Execute command  d:` before Get Directory but no luck there. Also is there a way to open a connection pointing to a specific volume?

Code I used:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library    SSHLibrary  timeout=120 seconds

*** Variables ***
${HOST_XP}          remote.win.xp.machine
${USER_XP}          user
${PASSWORD_XP}      pass
${DIR}              D:\\source\\

*** Test Cases ***
Test Win XP
    SSHLibrary.open_connection  ${HOST_XP}
    SSHLibrary.login  ${USER_XP}  ${PASSWORD_XP}
    SSHLibrary.get directory  ${DIR}
```

Edit1: various typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found out the problem for `Get Directory` method. In path variables `/` should be used and not `\`. So my DIR variable should be `${DIR}  D:/source/`

Comment: Interesting. Windows cmd environment is bizarre.